# OpenLayers 3 Remote JSON Data

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a remote JSON file with a list of houses in inventory. I wan't to plot these on an OL map. The JSON is coming from an API and isn't in standard GeoJSON. I need to get the coordinates from a collection called inventory which is nested one level down from the root object. How can I do this OL 3. In OL2 I did this using the protocol.Script() and on read parsing out the nested items that I needed. So far I have:

```
var myLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: "Inventory",
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
            projection : "EPSG:4326",
            url: "http://some.closed.api/inventory/",
            strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
        })
     })
 });
```

Any pointers to the most efficient way to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: OL won't parse your file if it's not a GeoJSON standard.

Comment: Many thanks @JonatasWalker, what is the alternative then? I guess I could parse the file in plain old JS and create the vector features...

Comment: Yes, you can add features parsing with JS, maybe you want to show a small part of your file structure.

Comment: Exactly.  You can look at ol3 format files to get some inspiration if you wish to create something "portable" and "re-usable".  Otherwise, parsing it manually and create your features yourself can do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this solution:

```
var olSource = new ol.source.Vector(),
    layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: olSource
    });

function successHandler( data ) {
    var transform = ol.proj.getTransform( 
        "EPSG:4326",
        map.getView().getProjection()
    );

    var rootObj = "inventory",
    items = data[ rootObj ] ? data[ rootObj ] : data;

    items.forEach( function( item ) {
        var feature = new ol.Feature( item );
        var coordinate = transform( 
            [ parseFloat( item.longitude ), parseFloat( item.latitude) ]
        );
        var geometry = new ol.geom.Point( coordinate );
        feature.setGeometry( geometry );
        olSource.addFeature( feature );
    });
}

$.ajax({
    url: "http://some.closed.api/inventory",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    params: { q: "seattle" },
    jsonpCallback: "callback",
    success: successHandler
});
```